# Downloading off gitlab onto Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, git, gitlab

I am very new to Ubuntu and have just downloaded it using WSL. I am trying to download something off of Gitlab but I get an error and have no idea where to start.
I am trying to download Foam-Extend 4.0 using this line of code:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/serfriz/foam-extend-4.0-ubuntu-20.04.git foam-extend-4.0
```

but the error i get is:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/serfriz/foam-extend-4.0-ubuntu-20.04.git/': Failed to connect to gitlab.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

I have not downloaded anything else but Ubuntu. Do I need other things, for example to create a Gitlab account or download and SSH?

I am very novice and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I can successfully clone the repo with the same command. It may be an issue with your internet connection. I am not sure if this is an Ubuntu (WSL) specific issue. Check if you can git clone in Windows shell.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, I should try run the same line of code in windows power shell?

Comment: Yes, install git for Windows, and check if the code works in Windows power shell. Otherwise, we cannot understand whether the issue is with your internet, or with Ubuntu.

Comment: So after installing git for Windows and running the same git line of code it successfully cloned the repository.

Comment: I think the problem might be that I had not set up a Gitlab account or set up a public ssh key. I have now started the process to set up a ssh key however I am stuck at the point where I have created a public ssh key, however I cannot find it now in order to paste it into my Gitlab account

Comment: I am stuck when inputting this line of code: 'xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub'                   I get the error: 'Command 'xclip' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install xclip'                                                                                                                      But when I enter that line of code to install xclip I get the error: 'E: Unable to locate package xclip'                                                                                                                                Can you please suggest what I can do?

Comment: I have solved the issue, thank you very much for your help

Comment: How did you solve the issue?

Comment: My antivirus firewall was blocking the connection and i needed to disable that to allow it to connect

Comment: Please write it into an answer, because it may help fellow users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by turning off my antivirus firewall (avast) as that was blocking the connection